# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, relationship

I have an issue on my project using Symfony2. Is a 'worklog' project, with tickets(issues) for a specific project. But when I try to edit a worklog entry I have this error :

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket could not be converted to
>   string

This is my db model :
[image]

And this is a part of the code from AppBundle/Entity/Worklog/

```
/**
 * @var \Ticket
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_ticket_id", referencedColumnName="ticket_id")
 * })
 */
private $ticketTicket;
```

And from AppBundle/Entity/Ticket/

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ticket_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $ticketId;
```

Do you have any idea why I have this errors ? Any idea to help ?

Worklog Form:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('worklogDate')
        ->add('worklogDuration')
        ->add('worklogDescription')
        ->add('ticketTicket')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Worklog'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'appbundle_worklog';
}
```

Comment: Do you have also the code for the form you're using to edit the worklog entry?

Comment: Did you clear the cache? `php app/console cache:clear -e dev`

Comment: I added the code from the Form. And the clear the cache is not working.

Comment: Add public __toString() method to your ticket entity class,  and return ticket name with it.

Comment: Thank you helios! Is working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your entity field not expected return.
try add:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getTicket();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't declare your fields fully in your `Form` class. It would be smth like this:

```
->add('ticketTicket', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Ticket',
    'property' => 'propertyName', //needed property's name
    'label' => 'choice_field_label'
))
```

If you need smth more complicated then just findAll for this field, you could use query_builder option:

```
->add('ticketTicket', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Ticket',
    'property' => 'propertyName', //needed property's name
    'label' => 'choice_field_label',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->findAllTicketNames(); 
        //Where findAllTicketNames is the name of method in your
        // ticketRepo which returns queryBuilder, 
        //instead of this you could just write your custom query like
        //$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('t');
        //$qb->andWhere(...);
        //return $qb;
    } 
))
```

p.s. 
my answer was copied from my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085795/advanced-form-symfony-2-7/34086944#34086944) and some little modifications were added to suit your case :)