# Advanced FORM Symfony 2.7

Tags: forms, symfony

i have a little problem with form. I have made form class and i need form field which will be like radio or select. Choices for select i need to pull from DB of another form. Here is the code so pls tell me where is my problem and how to solve it.

I want to have option when i create POST to choose from available pages (their names) and store that so i know for each post to which page it belongs and for each page i do query and show posts for that page..

```
<?php

 namespace AppBundle\AppForm;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use AppBundle\Entity\Page;

 class PostForm extends AbstractType {
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('content', 'textarea')
        ->add('visible', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Yes' => 1,
                'No' => 0
            )
        ))
        ->add('belongToPage', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array (
                new Page() 
           // here i want to pull from class Page names of 
           //all pages stored and to present
                // this names for options in form field
            ),
            'choices_as_values' => true,
            'choice_label' => 'getName' 
   //getName is function from class Page which returns name of page(s)

        ))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create Post'));
}

public function getName()
{
    // TODO: Implement getName() method.
}
}
```

Comment: if you are using doctrine and assuming there is a relationship, use the entity form type instead of the choice. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`entity` field type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html). It would be smth like this:

```
->add('belongToPage', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Class\Namespace\Class',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'choice_field_label'
    ))
```

If you need smth more complicated then just `findAll` for this field, you could use `query_builder` option:

```
    ->add('belongToPage', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Class\Namespace\Class',
        'property' => 'name',
        'label' => 'choice_field_label',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->findAllPagesForPostForm(); 
            //Where findAllPagesForPostForm is the name of method in your
            // pagesRepo which returns queryBuilder, 
            //instead of this you could just write your custom query like
            //$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('p');
            //$qb->andWhere(...);
            //return $qb;
        } 
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer i was looking for..
I have found info about entity type but i didnt know you can pass property in array so it was returning whole class and i got error like can not convert class to string type.. With property i can pull exactly what i need as a string..

Comment: @Constantine1001, no problem! Just mark it as answer :)